# Setup an SVN Server?

Tags: windows, svn

Does anybody know how to setup a basic SVN server on my windows pc? I want to create an SVN repository to store the code for my home projects I've got lined up.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at official documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06.html
It's a good start

Comment: Why would this belong on superuser?  I'd guess that most people on superuser don't even know what SVN is.

Comment: @Matthew, if it's considered to be suitable for any site other than SO, I'd personally suggest that it'd be ServerFault (as setting up an SVN server would/could/should be an administrative task) rather than SU, so I agree with you there... +1 :) (I hasten to add that I *haven't* put a "close" against this question)

Comment: @Rob, I'd agree that it would be better suited for SF than SU.  But I'd personally think it's best here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [install subversion on windows](http://serverfault.com/questions/31544/install-subversion-on-windows)

Comment: Belongs on Stack Overflow.  From SO FAQ, questions suitable for SO include questions about *software tools commonly used by programmers*

Answer (score 57):

Install [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).  The server part is free.  You can also just use any SVN tool to just create local repositories on your file system if you like.  My favorite client side tool is [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Comment: +1 for VisualSVN. I use it all the time for my home projects. Even if I never work with another developer, having SVN lets me keep track of changes I make over time, and revert mistakes after the fact. :)

Comment: I used to run a Linux server that I hosted SVN over SSH.  But I find VisualSVN on my Windows server as a much nicer option.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to just create local repositories with TortoiseSVN.  Really, a server is often overkill for personal projects...

Comment: +1 for both options. VisualSVN is a great 1-click solution, and there's nothing faster than local repos.

Comment: @MatthewWhited Thanks for the recommendation. Will my code online be in a private repository that is accessible to a few users (after granting access) or will it be a public repo and will my code be publicly visible to anyone?

Comment: It can be private or public.  That's up to you.  Though I would now suggest something like visual studio online or github so you don't have to worry about backups and patches.

Answer (score 17):

I can strongly recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/). It's very easy to setup, configure and use.

I've installed it recently and have found it utterly pain-free. SVN client-wise, I'd recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/). It integrates directly with Explorer and is, again, easy to use.

If you're working with Visual Studio, [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a great client that integrates into VS and doesn't seem to have any problem with being used side-by-side with TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 8):

I use [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) on my Windows 2008 server and it works great.  I then use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) on my client machines.  The installation is painless and you should be up and running in no time.

Answer (score 6):

If you are the only one accessing the repository all you need is tortoisesvn. You can make a local repository anywhere you want just by right clicking and selecting "Create Repository Here" then just use the file path for the URL.

Comment: Underrated comment. even after 10 years :)

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend Visual SVN if you like to get SVN installed on your Windows PC. There is a [nice tutorial](http://svnrating.com/how-to-setup-svn-server-on-windows/) that describes installation and configuration process.

However think twice before hosting your product locally as that isn't the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I would also Check out [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/).  Online hosting for both SVN and Git.  I have used both VisualSVN and Assembla for personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ubersvn](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn) for personal use it is working fine and it's freeware.

The program contains all the dependencies needed to set up and run an Apache Subversion server on Windows, Linux or Mac OS X operating systems
.[Check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UberSVN) this here

Comment: UberSVN is not available anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What is the final veredict? for a single user local repository what would be the best option:

- just create local repositories with TortoiseSVN (simpler and less
  resource consuming)
- install VisualSVN server to get the extra functionality it offers
  (for example, the automatic backups are quite interesting..)

The idea of using VisualSVN server in my local machine with the automatic backups stored in a google drive folder in order to keep the repository in case of catastrophe sounds good, but maybe is a bit overkill.. is it heavy the server initialization? the machine is only booted while I am working in my spare time.. if the server takes no negligible time to start every time I turn on the PC maybe the first option is better.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) it's not really an answer to the question you asked, but it might save you a lot of trouble.  You could also check the [VM marketplace](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/cat/0?k=subversion), there are many virtual machines that would get you up and running super fast.

Here's also a very nice one called [PMRepo](http://blog.sterlingheibeck.org/software/), it includes Trac, Subversion, and Hudson in one VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create SVN repo, you can use this [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/)

By using this tool, you can easily create SVN repo and it will give it's REPO URL. so you can use it for cloning. It is the easiest way to create repo in any machine and use the its repo URL

Answer (score -1):

before setting up SVN you need:
1.Install Putty http://www.putty.org/
2.Creat Droplet on Digital Ocean
3.Install Apache,Install PHP,Install phpMyAdmin

after that follow steps on below link:

https://progtec.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/how-to-setup-svn-server/