# How can I create the url for my repository in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am sorry if my question seems utterly simple, but I have read a few beginner's guide on TortoiseSVN and still couldn't find what I want.

How can I create the url for my repository? Must I host a server of some sort?

Basically my colleague is using a program I have written, and I am constantly updating the source codes. We are currently using windows local folder/file sharing and it is very inconvenient (I can't modify the files while she is using them). TortoiseSVN can definitely solve the problem but I am not sure how can I obtain the url for my repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need host a SVN server . you can install [Visual SVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) to create a SVN server. you can install this on the same machine as well.

you can also use different freemium online Source Control Management like [github](http://github.com), [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [TeamFoundationServer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx), [assembler](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/CommanderAssembler/trac_subversion_tool). These services use their own client github client and TFS client(comes integrated with Visual Studio).

Comment: WebSVN is not Subversion server. GitHub does not provide SVN hosting.

Comment: @bahrep GitHut *does* support access by Subversion, BitBucket *does not*.

Comment: @crashmstr yes, GitHub *supports Subversion clients*, but this does not mean that it's Subversion that they provide. It's Git repo with some svn-bridge used.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is an SVN client, what you are looking for is an SVN server, how to get one depends depends on your OS, check this question as a start

[Setup an SVN Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376742/setup-an-svn-server)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to setup an svn server, the @ilcavero's answer is right.

If you just trouble about how to setup an svn server, you can use Github or sourceForge.

github: www.github.com
sourceForge: www.sourceforge.net

and the private repository also can use in :https://bitbucket.org/

=====
edit 2016/01/11
What I mean is **not the git repo === svn repo**.
I just want to say that you can use git to replace the svn without setup a svn server.
 OK?

Comment: GitHub does not provide SVN hosting.

Comment: @bahrep From the [GitHub features page](https://github.com/features): "By the way, every GitHub repository is also a Subversion repository."

Comment: @crashmstr this is a great marketing move, but on practice it's just a mere "support for Subversion clients" and the support is very limited. Git repo != SVN repo.

Comment: @crashmstr *"Support for Subversion clients"*: https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/

Comment: @bahrep I guess it is also great marketing for a VisualSVN guy to say GitHub doesn't provide "SVN hosting" (which, while true, it not the whole truth either).

Comment: @crashmstr I don't know what I can say about the fact that GitHub does not provide hosting of Subversion except than say that it does not host SVN repos. It hosts Git repos through a bridge and provides limited support for basic client-side operations. If you use GitHub, use Git client, not Subversion client. Take a look at the OP's question.

Comment: You don't understand me!! What I mean is @Liren can use github without setup a server, not Git repo === SVN repo!

Comment: @bahrep the asker just want to use version control software. So! git is ok without setup a git server or SVN server! Do you understand me?'

Comment: @Alps1992 take a look at the question and its tags again, please.

Comment: @bahrep It's SVN. I saw that. but please see the first line of  my answer. I    have already said that ilcavero's answer about svn is right. my answer is a  piece of advice. Any question?